# The most used language for Debian

Tags: debian, programming

What is the programming language mostly used to develop most parts of the Debian?

Comment: How is this not “answered with facts and citations”?

Comment: What does "parts of Debian" mean? Is any random package a "part of Debian" even if no Debian Developer had any hand at all in its development?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most-used language is plain C; see the [sources statistics](http://sources.debian.net/stats/) for details. C represents 34.44% of Debian 9’s source code, 37.66% of Debian 10’s source code, and 37.23% of Debian 11’s source code (down from 76.29% of Debian 2.1’s source code).